# How to have an Input box in an md-menu item

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to have an option to add an item to existing list or create a new one; similar to youtube's 'Add to playlist'. The following kind of works but the menu goes away once there is focus on the input box. Is there a way to disable closing of menu on click of one item in the menu?

Environment is Angular 2 / material 2.

```
    <button md-raised-button  [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Add To</button>
    <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
      <md-input-container class="mx-4">
        <input mdInput placeholder="Create new" value="">
      </md-input-container>
    </md-menu>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it by stopping the `click` event propagation in the `<md-input-container>`.

html:

```
<md-input-container class="mx-4" (click)="stopPropagation($event)">
```

ts:

```
stopPropagation(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // console.log("Clicked!");
}
```

[plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/011ifsjbh2ekhvwYsrSo?p=preview)

Comment: Yes I got the same tip from https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2612#issuecomment-280156377; Thanks.

Comment: Ohh cool! I didn't know there was a github issue for this, thanks :)

Comment: angular material 8: `<div mat-menu-item [disableRipple]="true" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"><mat-form-field>...`